# ListView Item not clickable when I display ad's with PublisherAdView inside the Item

Tags: android, listview, adview

I need to display a custom PublisherAdView inside a ListView Item, but the item has an Action and if user clicks outside the Ad (witch leads to the sponsor url) this action must be called, (I know, it`s a strange Ad format, but they want this way).

The ListView item click works if the ad isn't loaded, but when PublisherAdView shows it, the listener won't work anymore.

This is the screenshot with some more info about what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Screnshot with some infos]

Here we have my code:

**Categoria.java**

```
ListView list=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id_categoria.list);

adapter = new CategoriaAdapter(getActivity(), listaRec);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

// Click event for single list row
 (new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {

        Bundle parametros = new Bundle();

        if (listaRec.get(arg2).get("vai").equals("patrocinada")) {
            //action of the list with the PublisherAdView.
        } else {
            //action for all other items.
        }

    }
}
```

**CategoriaAdapter**

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public CategoriaAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("session", 0);

        HashMap<String, String> dados = null;

        if(convertView==null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_categoria, null);
            dados = data.get(position);
        }

        TextView categoria = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lista_categoria_texto);
        LinearLayout layoutAd = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.lista_categoria_adView);

        // Setting all values in listview
        if (dados != null) {

            categoria.setText(dados.get("categoria"));

            if (dados.get("chave").equals("patrocinada"){

                layoutAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                List<AdUnit> adUnits = AdUnitList.getAdUnitByCategoria(Menu.adUnits, 0);

                /* No big deal here. this method just build the name of the DFP ID/ad position and call addView() to the layout I pass (layoutAd)
                 * Eg: /10101010/<my_prefix>_selomediabox in this case
                 */
                Ads.setAd(AdUnit.getAdUnit(adUnits, "selomediabox"), layoutAd, activity);
            }
        }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

**lista_categoria.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/select_item_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/lista_categoria_main"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lista_categoria_texto"
        style="@style/categoria_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lista_categoria_adView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lista_categoria_seta"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lista_categoria_seta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/seta_vermelha" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone knows what's happening to the PublisherAdView override my "list.setOnItemClickListener" ?

Thanks!